# I need a small credit card machine type printing device to print slips

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am working on a website which requires sending frequent info over the internet to various locations where that info can be printed. I was thinking of using raspberry pi, and a small credit card machine type printer. Will it be a good option to code python scripts that run on the raspberry pi? Anybody with experience in such a situation, please help me with what sort of device / printer would work fine. cost is a factor, so the more cheaper, the better. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question is pretty broad and not really specific. Please elaborate on which problem you are trying to solve and how it is related to electronics design.

Comment: Probably better (for lack of any other more general fitting SE) on raspberrypi.SE

Answer (score 3):

Look for the Raspberry Pi Thermal Printer.

Answer (score 2):

As Passerby mentioned, [there exists a project using the Raspberry Pi with a thermal printer](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/tag/thermal-printer). There is even example Python code to get you started.